# Autoit Click Keys together

Tags: key, send, autoit

How do I click in Autoit Keys together and not one after another.

In my case I want to click following:

```
CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + +
```

That would be this in Autoit:

```
   Send("{RCTRL}")          
   Send("{RALT}")           
   Send("{RSHIFT}")         
   Send("{+}")
```

But this does click the keys just one after another, but I want to click all at once. Is there any solution for this in autoit?

Answer (score 0):

Looked it up. I don't think you can select *right* shift specifically (or alt, or ctrl).

```
Send("!+^{+}")
```

or

```
Send("{SHIFTDOWN}{CTRLDOWN}{ALTDOWN}{+}{ALTUP}{CTRLUP}{SHIFTUP}")
```

Comment: ohh lol he just asked the same question again. If that does not wort idk.